# Appended content disappears after the change of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

On my webpage I am using Flask microframework. To give you better understanding of my problem I have decided to include several of my files. Hopefully I won't discourage you.

**Example** bare in mind this example is incomplete due to complexity of my website. But I hope it will ilustrate the problem.

My `script.py` which runs the server:

```
from flask    import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def home(name=''):
    return render_template('home.html', name=name)

@app.route('/user/')
@app.route('/user/<task>')
def user(task=''):
    return render_template('user.html', task=task)
```

Then I have `template.html`:

```
<!-- some html code -->
<div id="navBar"></div>

<div id="mainContent">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- some html code -->
```

and `user.html`:

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% if task == 'homework' %}
        {% include '/tasks/homework.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally my `script.js`:

```
// some jQuery script
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#navTask').empty();
    $('#navTask').append('\
                    <div class="task">\
                        <a href="/user/homework">Homework</a>\
                    </div>');
});
// some jQuery script
```

Back to my problem! Basically it does this. Once you click the `#button` it appends `#navTask` (which is `div` located somewhere on the page) with some `div` with link to `/user/homework`. Once you click on `Homework` Flask recognises the change of URL and renders `user.html` so some part of the webpage changes. My problem is: once you click the link `Homework` the link `Homework` disappears  too. I am not sure, how to fix it.

I thought, that by appending the `div.task` to `#navBar` it will changes throughout the webpage no matter the URL. But as far as I can tell it does not.

I am hoping for this behaviour - somewhere on the page there is a div, after clicking `#button`, the content changes and new link appears. When you click the link the content somewhere on the page changes, but the link stays where it was. The link might disappear e.g. only when you are on `home` page.

**Note** I am now quite sure, if my expectations are real. I could probably do this with just using jQuery, but because the `main.py` is much more complicated and I am using the data obtained from URL I still go this "way".

Comment: When the user clicks on /user/homework what template is rendered? Please include the source of that template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but you need to use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request triggered from click on the link if you don't want to refresh all page content.

Whenever was committed not Ajax request to server - the page will be completely redrawn.

On the server side you could check whether it [XMLHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) and if it is return JSON data or other convenient for you.

Maybe this little [flask-jquery-example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/) will help you.

P.S. Current location on JS side you can get by `window.location.pathname` or `$(location).attr('href')`

Comment: Sorry for very late response. I had so much work to be done and no time. But I used AJAX recently on different webpage so I will try to use it here.